# General formula for pairing members of array?

Tags: c++, algorithm, pairing

Hello guys I am having the following problem:

I have an array with a lenght that is a multiple of 4 e.g:

```
{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}
```

I want to know how can i get the numbers in the following pairs: {1,4},{2,3},{5,8},{6,7}.....(etc)

Suppose i loop through them and i want to get the index of the pair member from my current index

```
int myarr[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
**j= func(i)**
```

I have thought of something like this:

*f(1)=4*
*f(4)=1*
and i would be taking:   `**f(i)=a * i + b**`
 (i think a linear function is enough)
 It would result: **f(i)=j=-i+5** .
How can i generalise this for more then 4 members? What do you do in cases where you need a general formula for pairing elements?

Comment: Do I understand correctly that in general you want to break the array up into groups of four and then pair the first element of every group of four with the last element, and pair the middle two elements?

Comment: I don't want to break..i just need the index of the pair element J  that depends on the current index of the loop I.And yes i want them to be in that relationship : first with 4-th and second with third..while the array is indeed a multiple of 4.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, if `i` is odd `j` would be `i+3`, otherwise `j = i+1`;

```
int func(int i) {
    if(i%2 != 0)
        return i+3;
    else
        return i+1;
}
```

This will generate

```
func(1) = 4, func(2) = 3, func(5) = 8, func(6) = 7 // {1,4},{2,3},{5,8},{6,7}.
```

Comment: Thank you sir...damn i am so dumb and i wanted to get into software development...

Comment: Keeping learning, keep programming.  You'll get there.  Things are obvious to experienced developers because we've done it a 1000 times before.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as follows by keeping the incremental iteration but use a function depending on the current block and the remainder as follows.

```
int myarr[8]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

int Successor(int i)
{
    int BlockStart = i / 4;
    int Remainder = i % 4;
    int j = 0;
    if ( Remainder == 0 )
        j = 0;
    else if ( Remainder == 1 )
        j = 3;
    else if ( Remainder == 2 )
        j = 1;
    else if ( Remainder == 3 )
        j = 2
    return BlockStart + j;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    j = f(i);
    // usage of the index
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response but i want to loop through all the array..i dont want the increment condition changed.I just want to do something to the pair element ,what would the index of the pair element be?(assuming current element is I what J=f(I)..how do i calculate J at every iteration?

Answer (score 1):

About the generalization, this should do it:

```
auto pairs(const vector<int>& in, int groupLength = 4) {
    vector<pair<int, int>> result;
    int groups = in.size() / groupLength;
    for (int group = 0; group < groups; ++group) {
        int i = group * groupLength;
        int j = i + groupLength - 1;
        while (i < j) {
            result.emplace_back(in[i++], in[j--]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

You can [run this code online](http://ideone.com/HV9pZy).

If you are just looking for a formula to calculate the indices, then [in general case it's](http://ideone.com/kVH4hD):

```
int f(int i, int k = 4) {
    return i + k - 2 * (i % k) - 1;
}
```

Turns out your special case (size 4) is [sequence A004444 in OEIS](https://oeis.org/A004444).

In general you have ["nimsum n + (size-1)"](https://oeis.org/search?q=nimsum&sort=&language=&go=Search).

Comment: Thank you sir ...any piece of advice on how to get better at spotting these kinds of patterns,formulas?

Comment: @user1913744 I just formalized what you described in natural language into a mathematical function. I did it by example, thinking about concrete numbers and seeing what operations need to be applied to get to the result. So knowing what operations are available is one part. Second part is taking a small example and working it with pencil and paper, kind of like simulating a computer, noting every step of the process. From this, usually it should be possible to figure the instructions you want to give to the computer, so it can do the same you just did by hand.

Comment: In this particular case, the example that you want to work out with pencil and paper would be the one you posted: finding a pair for number 1, then finding a pair for number 2, then for number 3, and so on...